# Connect to a SharePoint 2010 site having SSO authentication using Powershell

Tags: sharepoint-server, powershell, csom, sso

I am trying to connect to a SharePoint Site having an SSO authentication using PowerShell. But i am unable to do so.

Please note, I am trying it from an external server so i have to do it using CSOM.

Can anyone help me with the script?

Comment: Maybe this helps a bit ? https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/d5921fdc-896e-4721-b9b8-31ebbf37227e/sso-active-login-to-office-365-sharepoint-using-csom-and-the-credentials-of-the-curent-users?forum=appsforsharepoint

Comment: By "SSO authentication" do you mean a Trusted Identity Provider (e.g., AD FS)?

Comment: Yes Adrain...But as a username it asks me only my UserID i.e.  joeldsouza and not my email id.

Comment: Sorry Charles, the link didn't help

Answer (score 0):

maybe the PNP authentication manager can help you :

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-Sites-Core/blob/master/Core/OfficeDevPnP.Core/AuthenticationManager.cs

in specific the class that will let you connect is the webClientauthenticationcontext

https://github.com/SharePoint/PnP-PowerShell